# Pyspark to pandas on small dataframe

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a large Spark dataframe with millions of row and 10 columns.
I aggregate this df to df1 by computing a sum over two groups: time and dummy. dummy takes value 0 or 1, time has approx 7000 days. So df1 is a small set of data.

```
df1= df.groupBy("time", "dummy").agg(sum("x3").alias("x3"))
```

I have to convert df1 to pandas, but conversion takes 15 minutes. How is this possible given the size of df1, and how can I speed up the conversion?

Fast conversion of df1 from Spark to Pandas

Comment: are you sure what's taking a long time is the convert to pandas and not the group by? Try to display df1 to see how long it takes.